# Python generate lat/long points from address

Tags: python, pandas, latitude-longitude, geopandas, geopy

How do I take addresses and generate lat, long coordinates from them in python? I have a few addresses that I would like get lat, long points but seems it doesn't work.

I used geopandas but it returns me nothing. I am also a bit confused about what to use for the **user_agent**. Here is my code,

```
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

df2['location_lat'] = ""
df2['location_long'] = ""

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="myApp")

for i in df2.index:
    try:
        #tries fetch address from geopy
        location = geolocator.geocode(df2['Location'][i])
        
        #append lat/long to column using dataframe location
        df2.loc[i,'location_lat'] = location.latitude
        df2.loc[i,'location_long'] = location.longitude
  
    except:
        #catches exception for the case where no value is returned
        #appends null value to column
        df2.loc[i,'location_lat'] = ""
        df2.loc[i,'location_long'] = ""
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you show some addresses that you are trying to find the lat, long for?

Comment: 1) 2094 Valentine Avenue,Bronx,NY,10457. 2) 1123 East Tremont Avenue,Bronx,NY,10460. 3) 412 Macon Street,Brooklyn,NY,11233. Here are some addresses. Thanks.

Comment: User_agent should be a rather unique string identifying your application. This could be your name, for example. The point is that it should be unique enough to ensure others don't use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `apply` directly on a DataFrame column:

```
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="myApp")

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Location':
            ['2094 Valentine Avenue,Bronx,NY,10457',
             '1123 East Tremont Avenue,Bronx,NY,10460',
             '412 Macon Street,Brooklyn,NY,11233']})

df2[['location_lat', 'location_long']] = df2['Location'].apply(
    geolocator.geocode).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(
        [x.latitude, x.longitude], index=['location_lat', 'location_long']))
```

It should give:

```
                                  Location  location_lat  location_long
0     2094 Valentine Avenue,Bronx,NY,10457     40.852905     -73.899665
1  1123 East Tremont Avenue,Bronx,NY,10460     40.840130     -73.876245
2       412 Macon Street,Brooklyn,NY,11233     40.682651     -73.934353
```

Comment: Hi, I did the same but I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'latitude'
Could it be that the addresses I have in my df are invalid?

Comment: @KenRusselSy: Indeed, I have not tested that with invalid addresses. The error message if probably caused by `geocode` returning `None` for at least one address.  You should split the operation in 2 steps (first just run `geocode`) to see what exactly happen.

Answer (score 1):

i made without pandas, but i think that you can use it

Code:

```py
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='your_app_name')

addresses = [
            '20, Willmannstraße, Fechenheim, Ost, Frankfurt am Main, Hessen, 60386, Deutschland',
            '20, Willmannstraße, Fechenheim, Ost, Frankfurt am Main, Hessen, 60386, Deutschland',
            'Pöhlen, Schönberg, Sandesneben-Nusse, Herzogtum Lauenburg, Schleswig-Holstein, 22929, Deutschland',
            'Pöhlen, Schönberg, Sandesneben-Nusse, Herzogtum Lauenburg, Schleswig-Holstein, 22929, Deutschland',
            'Pöhlen, Schönberg, Sandesneben-Nusse, Herzogtum Lauenburg, Schleswig-Holstein, 22929, Deutschland'
]

coordinates = []

for address in addresses:
    location = geolocator.geocode(address)

    lat, lon = location.latitude, location.longitude

    coordinates.append((lat, lon))

print(coordinates)

# output:
[(50.1262402, 8.767057053362574),
 (50.1262402, 8.767057053362574),
 (53.6805214, 10.4282207),
 (53.6805214, 10.4282207),
 (53.6805214, 10.4282207)]
```

I hope that helps you =D

Comment: The code returns a timeout error. Any reason why that would happen? Thanks.

Comment: i don't know man